# How to export typescript class but keep relate var private

Tags: typescript, tsc

Image this example:

```
const hidden = Symbol()

export class Foo {
  static [hidden] = 'I dont want another touch this'
}
```

The compiler report: error TS4028: Public static property '[hidden]' of exported class has or is using private name 'hidden'.

Yes I know 'hidden' is private. I just dont want export it.

Is there a way suppress this error?

Answer (score 3):

This is only an issue if you are emitting [declaration files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) with the `--declaration` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).  If you don't care about emitting declaration files, then disable the option and the error should go away.

If you *do* want to emit a declaration file, then there is an experimental compiler option, `--stripInternal`, which will not emit a declaration for any code annotated with `/** @internal */`.  Example:

```
const hidden = Symbol()

export class Foo {
    /** @internal */
    static [hidden] = 'I dont want another touch this'
}
```

This should silence the error.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Good to know about `stripInternal`. Alternatively, if you don't want to expose it, maybe you can keep it as module local variable?